# Flutter App signing Problem -- FormatException

Tags: android, flutter, release, sign, formatexception

I tried flutter doctor, clean, upgrade etc.
I read everything i found but i couldn't fix this.

What I want : Sign my apk

I made a keystore file : key.jks and i did everything about this page;
https://flutter.io/docs/deployment/android (just signing )

Problem is when i tried to build apk with

```
flutter build apk --release
```

I got an error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

and the logfile error is

```
FormatException: FormatException: Bad UTF-8 encoding 0x4c (at offset 511)
```

So if dont change `signingConfig signingConfigs.debug` to this `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` there is no error.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In the keystore.proporties file storeFile like this :

```
storeFile=D:\key.jks
```

I did it like this because Windows use `\`. But I changed it like this :

```
storeFile=D:/key.jks
```

And it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ try finding `Project settings -> "File Encodings"` and change `Project Encoding` to UTF-8.

Comment: Then please verify in your setting if you have `"files.encoding": "utf8"`, according to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

Comment: Yeah but there is a difference between setting it as default encoding for a project and actually saving each file with this encoding. Can you see `UTF-8` encoding for each file in bottom bar?

Comment: checked , nothing changed

Comment: It is possible for you to sign an example application from flutter? (could be any app with unmodified sources)

Comment: i tried to sign flutter example -- floating action button demo-- but it failed again

Comment: check if your imports are correct as explained in comments [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15793)

Comment: checked, and its actually not about utf-8, because for example if you are using an bad package -which is last updated package- you get an utf-8 error. Every error named utf-8 and i hate it. So in my example if you downgrade package, it works. I did it for firebase authentication. But signing apk is much more complicated. There is no downgradeable package. So  i cant solve it